# how to connect from Microsoft CRM to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, dynamics-crm, database-connection

We have a store site but we don't have online sell and our customer after visit our pages call us. so we can't track purchases through google analytics. 
We are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM and my question is how to connect crm to google analytics for tracking customer behavior and effectiveness of our media and advertising? 
for example the customer that purchase 200$ is from google ads or organic search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a system to get information from your CRM and send them to Google Analytics via Measurement Protocol: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1

Note: in order to reconnect the information to the Google Analytics user (i.e. source) you must save your clientId in the CRM and then send it with the transaction information to Google Analytics.

Comment: If your form is connected with the dynamics and you are getting the form information then you can send CientId along with the form data, which is later used to query google analytics for fetching the user information like source, medium etc.